# Do gitlab backups include the actual files in the repository?

Tags: git, gitlab, gitlab-omnibus

I'm running the following command every night:

```
gitlab-rake gitlab:backup:create
```

I've read the documentation:

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/raketasks/backup_restore.html

But, it isn't clearly stated: Does the backup also backup the files within the repository? Not just the repository history?

My apologies if this seems to be a stupid question.

Comment: It backup the repository, and from the repository you can rebuild a working copy, ie. the content of the files under revision control.

Comment: If they backup the repository they backup your files. The repository *is* your files.